# How to select shape of tensor for 1-D signal (accelrometer signal) ? I keep getting VlaueError due to tensor shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, valueerror, conv-neural-network

I am trying to model CNN for 1-D signal but I am unable to understand rank errors.

My program goes like this:

```
#Weights
def init_weights(shape):
    init_random_dist = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(init_random_dist)


#Bias
def init_bias(shape):
    init_bias = tf.constant(0.1,shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(init_bias)

def conv1d(x,W):
    #x is input accelration data and W is corresponding weight
    x = tf.cast(x, tf.float32)
    tf.nn.conv1d(x,W,stride=1,padding='VALID')

def convolution_layer(input_x,shape):
    w = init_weights(shape)
    b = init_bias([shape[3]])
    return tf.nn.relu(conv1d(input_x,w)+b)
```

- Now placeholders

  `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[1,1,200,1])`

  `y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,6])`

while creating 1st layer using `con_layer_1 = convolution_layer(x,shape=[1,20,1,32])` i get rank `ValueError` which i'm unable to degubg. Error statement is:

`ValueError: Shape must be rank 4 but is rank 5 for 'conv1d_20/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [1,1,1,200,1], [1,1,20,1,32].`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input and weights shapes to the `nn.conv1d` is not right. The input shape for the `nn.conv1d` should be of the size : `[ batch_size, input_length, input_channels]` and the weights matrix should be of size `[filter_size, inputs_channels, output_channels]`. So you need to change your code to :

```
def convolution_layer(input_x,shape):
   w = init_weights(shape)
   b = init_bias([shape[2]])
   return tf.nn.relu(conv1d(input_x,w)+b)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[1,200,1])

y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,6])

con_layer_1 = convolution_layer(x,shape=[20,1,32])
```

Note: You should try yo use `tf.layers` API that takes care of the weights assignment and all.